# Android Eclipse: How to reference library project's NDK library from another project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, libraries

I have an Android Eclipse library project "Lib" that contains both Java and C code built with the NDK.  I have another project "App", which is dependant on Lib.  App also contains both Java and C. My goal is to have multiple Eclipse App-like projects which each use the Lib project.

A Java routine in App calls a Java routine in Lib which calls C code in Lib.  This compiles, links, and runs perfectly on the device.

Now I want to add a call from the C code in App to the C code in Lib.  My First problem is header files.  I need to include a header file, jni/lib-jni,h, from the Lib project:

```
#include "lib-jni.h"
```

in a .c file in App.  For this #include to work I believe I need to add Lib's jni/ directory to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` in App's jni/Android.mk.  I do not want to hard-code this path, I would like to get it from Eclipse if possible.  After all, I've told Eclipse that the App project depends on the Lib project and Eclipse knows how to connect Java calls between the two.

I temporarily kludged around the first problem by copying lib-jni.h from Lib's jni/ directory to App's jni/ directory.  Now App's C code compiles, but it won't link; it gets an undefined.  In App's Android.mk I need to tell the C linker to link against libLib.so.  I tried putting -lLib on `LOCAL_LDLIBS`, but that didn't work.  libLib.so is in the Lib project in `Lib/libs/armeabi/libLib.so`.  Eclipse knows to incorporate this .so into the .apk file it builds for App.

**Is there a way to *cleanly* solve these two problems?**

1. Add Lib's jni/ directory to App's `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`
2. Add a reference to libLIb.so to App's `LOCAL_LDLIBS`

I phrased these problems in terms of possible solutions.  I'm open to any solution.  For example, if using `LOCAL_LDLIBS` the wrong way to go, what is the right way?

**Note**: Because App and Lib are two separate Eclipse projects built at separate times I am pretty sure I can not use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` in Lib's Android.mk to make Lib's jni/ directory available to App's Anroid.mk - I tried it didn't work.  But I'm prepared to be educated.

Answer (score 0):

I always set the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` to the original lib, so I think that is not that bad idea. An other solution is to include the external library as a static library in your libs folder, but I'm not sure if it will work.